# Double node on Xpath for different values

Tags: xpath

How to write a Xpath for two attributes? e.g. i need to get a value of discount > 20% and also the same discount is greater than amount 200(without any link to base value)

Comment: You should provide a sample of what you're looking for and specify what language you're writing this in.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine constraints in predicates. E.g.:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.XML("""<xml>
<items>
<item discount_perc="25" discount_value="250">Something</item>
</items>
</xml>
""")

doc.xpath('items/item[@discount_perc > 20 and @discount_value > 200]')
```

Comment: Just a styling thing, but maybe some people prefer it: You can also write `items/item[@discount_perc > 20][@discount_value > 200]`

Answer (score 0):

Will try to answer by a simple example. Imagine you have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
   <node value="10" weight="1">foo</node>
   <node value="10" weight="2">bar</node>
</data>
```

Then use this query to select the first `<node>`'s text:

```
//node[@value="10" and @weight="1"]/text()
```

and this for the second:

```
//node[@value="10" and @weight="2"]/text()
```

Hope this helps.